# Programatically create web application & sub site

Tags: sharepoint

I am using the following code to programatically create a web application & sub site,

```
            try
            {

                SPWebApplicationBuilder webAppBuilder = new SPWebApplicationBuilder(SPFarm.Local);

                SPWebApplication newApplication;
                int myPort = 3333;
                webAppBuilder.Port = myPort; //Port No.
                webAppBuilder.RootDirectory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\wss\\VirtualDirectories\\" + myPort);
                webAppBuilder.CreateNewDatabase = true; // Create new database

                webAppBuilder.DatabaseName = "WSS_Content_372772890a5a4a04abb460cd9ea3bd22";    // Database name
                webAppBuilder.DatabaseServer = webAppBuilder.DefaultZoneUri.Host;  // DatabaseServer Host name/computer name          

                webAppBuilder.UseNTLMExclusively = true;  // Use NTLM authentication

                newApplication = webAppBuilder.Create(); // Create new web application
                newApplication.Provision();           // Provision it into web farm           

                using (var mySiteCollection = newApplication.Sites.Add("/", "Site 3", "Site 3 Decscription", 1033, "STS#1", "In-Wai-Svr2\\Administrator", "Administrator", "tjagtap@waiin.com"))
                {
                    using (var rootWeb = mySiteCollection.RootWeb)
                    {                        
                        // Code customizing root site goes here                        

                        using (var subSite = rootWeb.Webs.Add("Site3.1", "Site 3.1", "Site 3.1 Description", 1033, "STS#1", true, false))
                        {                            
                            // Code customizing sub site goes here
                        }                        
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ;
            }
```

It works fine i.e. it creates the web application on the specified port with sub site but this sub site will not be shown under Sites menu of Quick launch bar also it will not be shown as a separate tab on the Home Page. Is it possible to do it programatically?

Answer (score 0):

"web application but the sub site does not appear as a separate tab on the home page"

I think that what you are trying to acomplish is to create a new website, inside the same application, for that you can't create a new application because it will create a new pool of sites. You have to create a new "sub"website inside the same application your home site is.

hope this helps:
[example](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-5-Programatically_create_a_SharePoint_site_based_on_a_site_definition.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
SharepointSiteService.Sites siteWS = new SharepointSiteService.Sites();
                                siteWS.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user1", "password", "domain");
try 
{

                                            SharepointSiteService.Template[] templates;
                                            siteWS.GetSiteTemplates(1033, out templates);
                                            SharepointSiteService.Template template = (from SharepointSiteService.Template t
                                            in templates
                                                                                       where t.Title == "Test Template"
                                                                                       select t).FirstOrDefault();

siteWS.CreateWeb("<parent web name>" + "/" + <sub web name>" + "/" + <sub web name>", "Test web", "Test Web", template.Name, 1033, true, 1033, true, 1033, true, false, false, false, false, false, false); 
}
catch (Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException e)
{
                                        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("SharePoint Foundation", "soap exception" + e.Detail + e.Message + e.Source + e.Node);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
                                        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("SharePoint Foundation", "Site Created");
                                        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("SharePoint Foundation", ex.Message + ex.Source + ex.StackTrace);
 }`enter code here`
```